# How to get product attribute value in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a very weird problem, I can get the product attribute value in local but when I go to the live server, I get an empty value. Magento version 1.6.2.

To get the attribute value, I use this code :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
$my_attribute = $product->getAttributeText('my_attribute');
```

PHP 5.3 and apache 2.2 on both local and live server

Comment: There's not a whole lot we can tell about your prod server ...

Comment: It's a debian. Local Windows 7 wampserver

Comment: If someone knows what can cause it to work on a server and not on another one. When I do a var_dump($product) I don't get my_attribute on the live server but I get it on local

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try these things :

```
    $attribute_option_id = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'my_attribute', $storeId);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setData('my_attribute', $attribute_option_id);

$text = $product->getAttributeText('my_attribute');
```

OR

```
    $_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
$_resource = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource();
$optionValue = $_resource->getAttributeRawValue($_id,  [ATTRIBUTE_ID/ATTRIBUTE_CODE], Mage::app()->getStore());
echo $optionValue;
```

OR

```
$attribute_value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks @girish-sh, I have tried all these. But what seemed to work is 
`if ($this->getItemOptions()):
 foreach ($this->getItemOptions() as $option):
  if ($option['label'] == 'My attribute'):
   $taille = nl2br($option['value']);
  endif;
 endforeach;
endif;` And this doesn't work for me on local

Comment: No error, and I get the correct value on the live server, but on local I get an empty value.